# Calling dispatch from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following custom hook:

```js
export const useCurrentUser = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(currentUserSelector);
  const preferredLanguage = useMemo(() => getUserAttribute(user, "preferred_language") || "en",
    [currentUser]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadAttributes(preferredLanguage));
  }, [preferredLanguage, dispatch]);

  return { preferredLanguage };
};
```

And this redux action:

```js
const _getDefaultAttributes = async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get("www.api.com/attr.json");
    // receive omitted...
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(failureAttributes(err));
  }
};

export const loadAttributes = (lang = null) => async dispatch => {
  if (!lang) {
    dispatch(_getDefaultAttributes());
    return;
  }

  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`www.api.com/attr-${lang}.json`);
    // receive omitted...
  } catch {
    _getDefaultAttributes(dispatch);
  }
};
```

The problem I have is that it makes about 40 requests. First `loadAttributes()` is called with `en` for `lang`, the api returns an error, since it does not have attributes for `en`, then it defaults to loading the default attributes. Here is a screenshot of the Network tab:

[image]

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Are you sure the API is working? I try `www.api.com/attr.json` in my browser and getting error

Comment: `www.api.com` is not a real API. And yes, it is working.

Comment: @tdranv My guess is that `getUserAttribute` is returning a different `prefferedLanguage` causing the effect to run again. Why are you not getting `prefferedLanguage` from redux store?

Comment: It's not that as well. I tried setting `const prefferedLanguage = "en"` but it is still calling it ~40 times.

Comment: How many components use the hook?

Comment: I think Nadia might be on to something.  Every instance of the hook manages its own `useEffect` so you'll want the actions themselves to not do anything if a request has already been started.

Comment: Good catch, Nadia! The hooks is used in 2 components only but one of them is a component that is `.map()`ed from an array. So the array has ~40 items, which means ~40 requests. Didn't know that about hooks. Thank you.

Comment: P.S. - I moved the dispatching higher up the component hierarchy and its all good now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova, you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @tdranv done, maybe will help someone else struggling with hooks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a common assumption that custom hooks can be used to share state between components, but actually they are not much more than normal javascript functions. The code inside a hook will behave in the exact same manner as if it was placed inside the component that is using it. This means that all `useState` and `useEffect` calls will be executed independently by each component instance (by all 40 component instances in this case :) ).